# The acceptability of verbal phrase ellipsis and subject-auxiliary inversion in triple modal sentences

Tags: english, modal-verbs, grammaticality, ellipsis, inversion

I have been researching on multiple modal constructions, which is a feature used in the Southern United States. Unlike Standard English, this dialect allows more than one modal auxiliary per clause.
For example, some speakers of this dialect may say, "You might could go to the store for me."

What I would particularly like to know is about verbal phrase ellipsis and subject-auxiliary inversion of the multiple modal sentences.

I would like to ask researchers on multiple modal constructions used in The Southern United States about the grammaticality or acceptability of the following sentences.

**about verbal phrase ellipsis**:

(1)

```
   a.  I might could should do that, and you might could should too.
   b.  I might could should do that, and you might could too.
```

(2)

```
   a.  Rose might will can't come tomorrow, but Joe might will can.
   b.  Rose might will can't come tomorrow, but Joe might will.

   a.  Rose might will can come tomorrow, and Joe might will can too.
   b   Rose might will can come tomorrow, and Joe might will too.
```

**about subject-auxiliary inversion**

(1)

```
   a.  Could I might should do that?
   b.  Should I might could do that?
```

(2)

```
   a.  Will Rose might can't come tomorrow?
   b.  Can't Rose might will come tomorrow?
```

Comment: might could etc. is merely a non-standard form. It is used instead of might be able. It is common among non-schooled speakers and fine. But I have never heard those inverted ones. Did you make those up? If not, where do they come from? Also, never heard "might will".

Comment: I appreciate your valuable comment. I made up the inverted versions because I wanted to know which auxiliary bears Tense. I draw "might will" from <https://multimodal.library.sc.edu/table.html>, but your comment is also important.

Comment: As I said, I've only ever heard/seen "might could". There is also in that database, "might should".

Comment: If you don't mind, I would like you to tell me where you are from. multiple modal constructions are a kind of dialect used mainly in the southern U.S., so whether you are Southerner or not may affect your experience.

Comment: I can do that but I really do not appreciate your telling me what a form with two modals is. I think I have shown that I understand them. I am not a southerner but studied in the south and have southern family members. BUT, well-educated southern speakers do not use those forms. It is not a kind of dialect. It is usage in the south much like "I ain't gonna say nothin'. Same idea. It's not just any two modals. It's mostly could and should.

Comment: And lastly, anything anyone says is acceptable if you are studying people's speech.

Comment: I apologize to you for my comments.

Comment: OK, thank you for that.